# More than four color mixes results in mesh turning pink (Eevee)

Tags: texturing, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I have a group of texture colors and color mixes that mix them together into one shader. There is a value counter that changes which texture shows on the mesh (If value=0, then switches to texture#0. If value=1, then switches to texture#1, etc.(This is done with *greater than* math variables))[image] It works fine, except when I try to add a fifth color texture and mix it in with the others. When I do that, the mesh turns pink even though there are no missing textures. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I know there's a hard limit somewhere (although your graph looks too small to hit it), it's possible that you have indeed reached it (might have something to do with what's contained in your node groups). If everything you connected worked right up until the last connection, and that final one turned the whole thing pink, either there's something wrong with that last group (Angry), or you have hit the limit. If that's the case, only thing you can do is try to simplify, I'm afraid.